# How do I exit the window manager on the current X display?

Tags: debian, x11, xorg

Let's say I have the window manager Blackbox running on two different X displays, e.g. `:0.0` and `:1.0` launched from `tty1` and `tty2` respectively. From a terminal (emulator), how do I exit (kill) the Blackbox process that uses the current X display? The command `killall blackbox` does not fit since it terminates both sessions.

Comment: you can use `ps ux` to find the process. Then `kill` to kill.

Comment: @richard , i've expanded your comment into an answer . and your `ps` usage seems different than mine . i want environment variables as well as commandline arguments . what flavour of unix system are you working on ?

Comment: @richard This will give me the tty (seventh column) for each Blackbox process but in the general case I don't know which one is running on the current display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution inspired by soubunmei's answer:

```
#!/bin/sh

ActiveWindowManagerPID()
{
    local windowManager="$1"

    local windowManagerPIDs="$(pidof "$windowManager")"

    local displayNumber="$(echo $DISPLAY \
        | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[:.]" } { print $2 }')"

    ps e -p "$windowManagerPIDs" \
        | awk -v n="$displayNumber" \
            '$0 ~ " DISPLAY=:" n "[\n .]" { print $1 }'
}

kill "$(ActiveWindowManagerPID blackbox)"
```

Answer (score 1):

`ps e` lists processes with their commandline along with ( initial ? ) environment variables . filter processes matching either a `-display :0` commandline or a `DISPLAY=:0` environment . i believe this find the wm in question whether started manually or by some session script . then we can simply `kill` it .

---

i hear there are different ps implementations , the above ( bsd ? ) commandline style works on my machine with debian procps-ng . refer to the manual if necessary .

---

based on the observation that wm is owner of the *root window* , [this arch wiki page has a minisection](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Manually) with an approach of `xprop -root _NET_WM_PID` to find the pid , . but this don't work for me , seemingly because it is only voluntary for x windows to provide this property , and my wm happens to not follow that fashion .

regarding other nonworking ideas , xkill can detach clients *except* the root window , so don't fill our need here .

Comment: Thanks for the input, I wasn't familiar with the `e` option. One strange thing about the output from `ps e` is that there is no space between the command and the environment variable following it, for instance `blackboxMAIL=/var/mail...`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom , you are right about "cannot xkill root window" , let me delete that answer and put some small information regarding xwininfo and xprop into this answer .

Answer (score 0):

If you have identified the tty where you lauched the blackbox from, `ps -t tty1` will list the processes launched from that terminal (assuming tty1 is the one from where you launched the openbox you want to kill), then you can identify and kill the one you want.

Comment: That's correct but in the general case I don't know. In my solution posted here I instead start from the `DISPLAY` variable.